# getting error : contours is not defined for my hand-web-browser project

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I am trying to build a project "hand_web_browser", the primary objective of this project is to open web pages using hand-gestures. But, I am getting an error at line 55 which says

> cnt = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

> NameError: name 'contours' is not defined

If anyone could help me with the issue???

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import webbrowser as wb
import os

print("Enter full website for")

print("\n2 fingers")
fingers2 = input()

print("\n3 fingers")
fingers3 = input()

print("\n4 fingers")
fingers4 = input()

tabs = 0
count = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (cap.isOpened()):
    # read image
    ret, img = cap.read()

    # get hand data from the rectangle sub window on the screen
    cv2.rectangle(img, (400, 400), (100, 100), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    crop_img = img[100:400, 100:400]

    # convert to grayscale
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # applying gaussian blur
    value = (35, 35)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey, value, 0)

    # thresholdin: Otsu's Binarization method
    _, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # show thresholded image, not necessary and can be skipped
    cv2.imshow('Thresholded', thresh1)

    # check OpenCV version to avoid unpacking error
    (version, _, _) = cv2.__version__.split('.')

    if version == '3':
        image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    elif version == '2':
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # find contour with max area
    cnt = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

    # create bounding rectangle around the contour (can skip below two lines)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 0)

    # finding convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

    # drawing contours
    drawing = np.zeros(crop_img.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 0)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [hull], 0, (0, 0, 255), 0)

    # finding convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt, returnPoints=False)  # return point false to find convexity defects

    # finding convexity defects
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
    count_defects = 0
    cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)  # to draw all contours pass -1

    # applying Cosine Rule to find angle for all defects (between fingers)
    # with angle > 90 degrees and ignore defects
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]  # [ start point, end point, farthest point, approximate distance to farthest point ]

        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])

        # find length of all sides of triangle
        a = math.sqrt((end[0] - start[0]) ** 2 + (end[1] - start[1]) ** 2)
        b = math.sqrt((far[0] - start[0]) ** 2 + (far[1] - start[1]) ** 2)
        c = math.sqrt((end[0] - far[0]) ** 2 + (end[1] - far[1]) ** 2)

        # apply cosine rule here
        angle = math.acos((b ** 2 + c ** 2 - a ** 2) / (2 * b * c)) * 57

        # ignore angles > 90 and highlight rest with red dots
        if angle <= 90:
            count_defects += 1
            cv2.circle(crop_img, far, 1, [0, 0, 255], -1)
        # dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,far,True)

        # draw a line from start to end i.e. the convex points (finger tips)
        # (can skip this part)
        cv2.line(crop_img, start, end, [0, 255, 0], 2)
        # cv2.circle(crop_img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)
    if count == 0:
        cv2.putText(img, "Wait for it :p", (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, 3)
    # define actions required
    if count_defects == 1 and count != 2 and tabs <= 8:
        wb.open_new_tab('http://www.' + fingers2 + '.com')
        tabs = tabs + 1
        cv2.putText(img, "2." + fingers2, (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
        count = 2
    elif count_defects == 2 and count != 3 and tabs <= 8:
        wb.open_new_tab('http://www.' + fingers3 + '.com')
        tabs = tabs + 1
        cv2.putText(img, "3." + fingers3, (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        count = 3
    elif count_defects == 3 and count != 4 and tabs <= 8:
        wb.open_new_tab('http://www.' + fingers4 + '.com')
        cv2.putText(img, "4." + fingers4, (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255, 165, 0), 3)
        tabs = tabs + 1
        count = 4
    elif count_defects == 4 and count != 5:
        cv2.putText(img, "5.Close Web browser", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, 3)
        os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
        tabs = 0
        count = 5
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "", (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, 3)

    if count == 2:
        cv2.putText(img, "2." + fingers2, (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
    elif count == 3:
        cv2.putText(img, "3." + fingers3, (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    elif count == 4:
        cv2.putText(img, "4." + fingers4, (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255, 165, 0), 3)
    elif count == 5:
        cv2.putText(img, "5.WebBrowser close", (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, 3)

    # show appropriate images in windows
    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)
    all_img = np.hstack((drawing, crop_img))
    # not necessary to show contours and can be skipped
    cv2.imshow('Contours', all_img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using a latest version of OpenCV. If you are using something like `4.x.x`, try the following code.

```
if version == '4':
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
elif version == '2':
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

The reason for the error is that your code is not extracting the contours at all, because the statement `(version, _, _) = cv2.__version__.split('.')` returns `4` and your "if and else" both fail.

Please note the following line of code as well.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

This is changed because

> Since OpenCV 3.2, findContours() no longer modifies the source image.

I hope this will solve your issue.